# security for eventmachine web service

Tags: web-services, security, eventmachine

I am exposing a webservice using eventmachine and evma_httpserver as follows:

```
EM.run{
  puts "Query Server running on port 9000"
  EM.start_server '0.0.0.0', 9000, QueryEngineHttpServer
}
```

I would like to make it secure, i.e., require a user name and password.  I know how to do this using Sinatra, but I'm not using it for this, so I'm no sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

which kind of authentication do you need? Basic-auth or cookie based?

is this something that can help you ?

```
module QueryEngineHttpServer
  include EM::HttpServer

  def post_init

    # if you want the connection to be encrypted with ssl
    start_tls({:private_key_file => path_to_key_file,
               :cert_chain_file => path_to_key_file,
               :verify_peer => false})

    # don't forget to call super here !
    super
  end

  def process_http_request

    # Block which fulfills the request (generate the data)
    operation = proc do

        # depending of which kind of auth you want you should have to parse the cookie or the 'autorization' header
        auth = check_for_auth @http_cookie, @http_headers

        # create the response object to be used in the EM::defer callback        
        resp = EM::DelegatedHttpResponse.new(self)
        resp.status = auth ? 200 : 401
        resp.content = 'some content here...'
        resp
    end

    # Block which fulfills the reply (send back the data to the client)
    response = proc do |reply|
      reply.send_response      
    end

    # Let the thread pool handle request
    EM.defer(operation, response)
  end

end
```